# Safari Bug: rotateY and rotateX element under fixed element

Tags: html, css, safari

[image]

The gray image with the hands scrolls up using translate. It has a fixed position. The dog image cutting through has the following styles:

`transform: scale(1.025) rotateY(..) rotateX(..)`

Only happens in Safari. Seems like the rotated dog image doesn't like being under fixed elements. This also happens when the image is scrolled beneath the nav bar (also fixed position).

Anyone know a fix for this? I've tried putting different transform properties on different elements, no fix yet.

Comment: you'd have to post some code for anyone to be able to dig into this

Comment: also, could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? it's not clear from what you've said what your intended result was, and how that differs from the screenshot you posted

Comment: The screen shot shows a bug in safari where the transformed image below the fixed, gray container is cutting through the gray container, when it should remain behind it. That was the issue I was trying to solve, but I found a solution. @danyamachine

Answer (score 2):

Adding `translate3d(...)` to the fixed element above the dog image fixed the problem.

I also added `perspective: 9999` to the parent element containing the grid of images.

Answer (score 1):

I suffered from the same issue. After few try, I fixed it by add `tranlateZ(some value which is important)` which separate these two layer into two level.

Comment: If there are any problems, please feel free to contact me.